# How to design my database with special relations?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, database-design, foreign-keys

Well, my database is really particular. The part I dunno how to design is the next one :

I need to have an entity "Scan" which will contain a FK to an other entity.

The problem is that the "other entity" could be from different entities : Type1Entity, Type2Entity, Type3Entity and these entities haven't any relation between themselves.

It's a many-to-one relationship.

So for exemple, I want to have 2 entities "Scan" : 
- one with a FK to Type2Entity and the second one to the Type3Entity.

Does anyone have any idea for me?

By the way, I don't want to have to do this :

Table "Scan" with the 3 FK :
   Type1EntityID
   Type2EntityID
   Type3EntityID
and 2 of the 3 to null value.

Thank you verymuch !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most of the time, you can merge those Entity tables and use one auxiliary field to differentiate them.

If you can't do that, in most case like this, there are some common fields between your TypeXEntity tables.

If so, one solution is you extract the common part of those Entity tables and create a new table (call it EntityTypeCommon). Then create FK from EntityTypeCommon to Scan table and then create FK from the individual Entity tables to EntityTypeCommon

```
Scan(
  Id
  Name
)

EntityTypeCommon(
  Id
  ScanRef
  ...
)

Entity1Type(
  Id
  TypeEntityCommonRef
  ...
)

Entity2Type(
  Id
  TypeEntityCommonRef
  ...
)

Entity3Type(
  Id
  TypeEntityCommonRef
  ...
)
```

Answer (score 1):

You have poor database design in the first place. You should not use different tables for different types of `Entity`. Instead create a single table for all your `Entity` with a column `EntityTypeId`. Then create another table for `EntityType`. Like this:

```
Entity
    Id              INT
    EntityTypeId    INT
    --Other columns

EntityType
    Id      INT 
    --Other columns

Scan
    Id          INT
    EntityId    INT
    --Other columns
```

Then you can have an FK on `Scan` thru `EntityId`.

Answer (score -1):

Type1, Type2, Type3, etc. are a classic case of class/subclass or, if you prefer, type/subtype.  These cases have been studied in depth for decades, and you can benefit by learning from those who have gone before.  To start with, I suggest you look at these three tags, studying the questions, the answers, and also the description in the info tab.

[single-table-inheritance](/questions/tagged/single-table-inheritance)
[class-table-inheritance](/questions/tagged/class-table-inheritance)
[shared-primary-key](/questions/tagged/shared-primary-key)